# In postgresql, how to count runs in a sequence across repeating partitions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, aggregation, gaps-and-islands

I have a user who has done a sequence of events. I want to capture the number of times they have done each event and in which order.

So for the following table *user_events*:

```
name  eventname  time    
Ted   a          12:01
Ted   b          12:02
Ted   b          12:03
Ted   b          12:04
Ted   c          12:05
Ted   b          12:06
Ted   b          12:07
Ted   c          12:08
Ted   b          12:09
Ted   b          12:11
Ted   b          12:12
```

I should get:

```
name  eventname  event_sequence_number  time_started  frequency
Ted   a          1                      12:01         1
Ted   b          2                      12:02         3
Ted   c          3                      12:05         1
Ted   b          4                      12:06         2
Ted   c          5                      12:08         1
Ted   b          6                      12:09         3
```

I've been attempting with *rank(), dense_rank(), row_number()* and *lag()* but can't put it all together. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It uses the Tabibitosan method ( grouping sequence ranges ) : [Toolbox](https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/ganotedp/tabibito-san-the-traveler-technique-in-sql-080216)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/95ad1/36)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE user_events
    (user_name varchar(3), eventname varchar(1), event_time time)
;

INSERT INTO user_events
    (user_name, eventname, event_time)
VALUES
    ('Ted', 'a', '12:01'),
    ('Ted', 'b', '12:02'),
    ('Ted', 'b', '12:03'),
    ('Ted', 'b', '12:04'),
    ('Ted', 'c', '12:05'),
    ('Ted', 'b', '12:06'),
    ('Ted', 'b', '12:07'),
    ('Ted', 'c', '12:08'),
    ('Ted', 'b', '12:09'),
    ('Ted', 'b', '12:11'),
    ('Ted', 'b', '12:12')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.user_name
    ,t.eventname
    ,row_number() OVER (
        ORDER BY MIN(event_time)
        ) AS event_sequence_number
    ,MIN(event_time) AS time_started
    ,COUNT(*) as frequency
FROM (
    SELECT user_name
        ,eventname
        ,event_time
        ,row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY event_time
            ) - row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY eventname ORDER BY event_time
                ,eventname
            )  seq
    FROM user_events
    ) t
GROUP BY user_name
    ,eventname
    ,seq
ORDER BY time_started
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/95ad1/36/0)**:

```
| user_name | eventname | event_sequence_number | time_started | frequency |
|-----------|-----------|-----------------------|--------------|-----------|
|       Ted |         a |                     1 |     12:01:00 |         1 |
|       Ted |         b |                     2 |     12:02:00 |         3 |
|       Ted |         c |                     3 |     12:05:00 |         1 |
|       Ted |         b |                     4 |     12:06:00 |         2 |
|       Ted |         c |                     5 |     12:08:00 |         1 |
|       Ted |         b |                     6 |     12:09:00 |         3 |
```

Comment: Beautiful piece of code - I had created something similar in the end. Extremely useful for creating a cleaner path analysis from aggregating millions of online user behaviour.